# How to change layer’s CRS in order to buffer and intersect in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, buffer, intersection, overlay

[image]

I'm very new to QGIS (working with version 3.12).

I'm trying to create a buffer of rail lines, but it's coming out much larger than it should be, e.g. when I try to show a 500-ft buffer, it results in a large circle whose radius far exceeds 500 ft.

I changed the CRS of both the QGIS project itself and the line so that they match, but with the same result. I'm also trying to do an intersect overlay with a line and a polygon and while the resulting layer appears on the panel, it does not appear in the project itself. Again, I matched up the CRS's of the two layers but to no avail.

Something is telling me these two issues are linked. Which problem(s) might I be having? I've attached an image for reference; that little black dot in the middle of the circle are the zoomed-out rail lines from which I'm trying to create a buffer. Again I'm very new to this so please explain as simply as possible as there's quite a bit of terminology I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to reproject a layer is to right-click it in the *Layers* panel and *Export-> Save features as...*.
In the following dialogue you choose the CRS you would like to reproject to and the format and name of the output. The reprojected layer will be added to the *Layers* panel by default.

An equally easy alternative for reprojection is the *Reproject layer* algorithm. It can be found in the *Processing Toolbox*.

If you use *Set CRS*, you tell QGIS that the coordinates in the layer are in that CRS (that the layer's CRS is wrong) - this is ***Not*** what you want (but is a mistake that many have made before you).